# Delve for a particular sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, delve

We have multiple sharepoint sites where people collaborate. Delve is an excellent tool for finding what's going on and who's working on which documents, however, we would like to put a particular focus on one sharepoint site, so that the team who has access to that site has almost its own, dedicated Delve, separate from everything else. This is because that site would be their main work area, and while they have access to many other sites, any update done here, must absolutely be highlighted to the whole team.